# background image not showing using css

Tags: html, css, background-image

I am trying to write into the CSS to show an image as the background and make it cover the page.

I am using the following code saved as css/varPractice.css

```
body {
background-image: url("img/beautifulPic.jpg");
background-size: cover;
background-image: no-repeat;
}
```

and have the following line in my html doc.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/varPractice.css">
```

however no pictures shows at all.  This is the only style sheet link in that html file.

Any advice?

Comment: My problem was actually that my image was in folder img on the main directory not inside the css --> img folder, the console told me the directory wasn't found. I am very new to programming, I am just writing some pages in brackets for practice and fun.

I do appreciate the feedback, once I fixed the file path it worked fine, I did switch background-image to background-repeat but in this instance seemed to have no effect, not repeating either way.

Comment: better practice to get into the habit of creating a css folder. As you progress you'll may find yourself using numerous stylesheets... start now! (using the folder i mean..) :)

Answer (score 2):

Try to remove the background-image: repeat;
It should be background-repeat: repeat;
You were overwriting the background image.

Answer (score 2):

You are redeclaring `background-image`.  It looks like you meant to use [`background-repeat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-repeat).

Your rule should read as follows:

```css
body {
  background-image: url("img/beautifulPic.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Joseph,  so when adding an image for the background from the css the url will automatically attempt to look in the same folder as the CSS? Is this correct?

Comment: @RobHudson It depends on what path you use.  With what you have now, yes, it would behave that way.  relative paths (i.e. ones that don't begin with a slash or a protocol like http or https) will be relative to the stylesheet.  I highly recommend using absolute paths.  in your case it would probably just be `/img/beautifulPic.jpg` for that path.  This effectively ensures that the resource is loaded relative to the site root.